# Per tag sidebar links?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've noticed that [on this page](https://stackapps.com/questions/585/droidstack-for-android-1-0-8) on stackapp there's a handy sidebar with links under "Get Started"

I was wondering if it was possible to get on Ubuntu SE with individual tags, so that for example when people go to kernel answers they have a link to existing resources that that ubuntu team might provide. The existing box seems to be just the top FAQ questions but I am not sure.

An example would be a question like "How do I write an application and get it in the software center?" on the side there would be a link to getting started with quickly, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding those links are more-or-less "hard coded" on any stackApp. I know that StackExchange, LLC has just recently rolled out the "featured" tag:

> If you want to manually place meta questions on the meta house ad (appears on every question on every page) tag the meta question [featured]

But this seems to be for meta questions to appear on the side bar - not sure if we should (or even could) apply it to something like you mentioned.